# How do I style text in console using php? [running in PHP CLI]

Tags: php, command-line, styles

How do I style text in console using php? [running in PHP CLI]

Lets say that I want to have yellow bold text with blue background:

EDIT:

The code below is just an example, I am well aware that it is not working. I asked this question before and people told me that I have to be more specific.

```
echo "Lorem unem ipsum. <span style="color: yellow; font-wieght: bold; background-color: blue;">This is yellow bold text with blue background.</span> Dip dunem sipsum."
```

Comment: Do you mean running in PHP CLI?

Comment: On Windows or a *NIX'alike

Comment: Yes I edited the question. I have no background in linux nor I have experience in "real programming languages" that is kind of the reason why I could not find answer to my question on the internet. I am not really sure what am I looking for.

Comment: The CLI is not a browser and therefore HTML/CSS has no effect

Comment: I know that. Thank you.

Comment: So why does your example use HTML and CSS?

Comment: http://blog.lenss.nl/2012/05/adding-colors-to-php-cli-script-output/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're aiming to output to a *nix console, you need to use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). There are some packages you can use that wrap these escape codes in an easy API, like [ansi-php](https://github.com/bramus/ansi-php).

Comment: I love your second link. I will probably mark this as answer. I know how to use php artisan and symfony console but I was thinking about building my own minimalistic tool for fun. bramus/ansi-php look easy enough to replicate.

Answer (score 7):

```
echo "\033[32m". "coloured green text\n";
echo "\033[37m"."white text\n";
```

use google! Some examples: [PHP Class for Coloring PHP Command Line (CLI) Scripts Output](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-class-for-coloring-php-command-line-cli-scripts-output-php-output-colorizing-using-bash-shell-colors/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any official documentation though? One that would list all the styles that I can apply to the text.

Comment: [Bash/Prompt customization: Colors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Colors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://packagist.org/packages/php-parallel-lint/php-console-color

my simple example:

```php
$consoleColor = new \PHP_Parallel_Lint\PhpConsoleColor\ConsoleColor();
echo $consoleColor->apply("bg_color_118", "SUCCESS" . PHP_EOL);
echo $consoleColor->apply("bg_color_197", "FAILED" . PHP_EOL);
```